# suitable statistical method for variables dependency testing

Tags: statistics, chi-squared

I made a survey among small and medium enterprises and I asked two questions:

Q1: How many employees does Your enterprise have ?

1. none, 2. 1 to 9, 3. 10 to 19, 4. 20 to 49, 5. at least 50.

Q2: How difficult is to gain resources such as finances, qualified workers etc. for You ?

1. very difficult, 2. difficult, 3. normal, 4. easy, 5. vey easy.

I recorded all possible combinations of answers and got the following results:

[image]

The table represents how many survey respondents chose a particular combination of answers. The first column is for Q1 and the first row is for Q2. The rows say how many participants chose which answer in Q1 and the columns say how many of them chose which answer in Q2. A cell shows how many participants chosed a particular combination of answers for Q1 and Q2, e.g. the cell in 2nd row and 2nd column shows that 3 participants chose answer 1 for Q1 and answer 1 for Q2.

My goal is to prove that the increment of number of employees coincides with the increment of ability to gain resources, there is some dependency between these two variables. From the table, the validity of such statement is clear since the highest values are close to the diagonal. However, I do not know how to prove it. I am new to statistical methods and I am looking for a simple (statistical or economical) method that is doable in excel. Something like the correlation coefficient. I already learnt that chi square test is not suitable for such results since some of the expected values are smaller than 1.

I am very grateful for any of your ideas in comments or in answers.